# ViewCell ForceUpdateSize not working sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using a custom ViewCell in Xamarin Forms which looks like this:

```
public class NativeCell : ViewCell
{
    public double Height
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Height;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Height = value;
            ForceUpdateSize();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also created a method to animate the colapse of the ViewCell which works as expected. However, with the overlay that comes with await, each loop iteration lasts up to 100ms instead of 1ms:

```
async public void Colapse()
{
    for (double i = Height; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Height = i;
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

So I made another method that used the Stopwatch to do the waiting:

```
async public void Colapse()
{
    var Timer = new Stopwatch();

    for (double i = Height; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Height = i;

        Timer.Start();
        while(Timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < 1)
        {
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("-->" + Timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        Timer.Reset();
    }
}
```

This last method reports that the wait time is now usually 1.1ms - 1.3ms. Which is great. However, the Height asignment is not doing anything. Or at least ForceUpdateSize is not triggering.

Comment: Have you tried to set HeightRequest instead of ForceUpdateSize

Comment: @YuriS ViewCell's don't have a HeightRequest property. I believe this issue has something todo with the fact that await returns control to the caller. So I also tried wrapping Height in Device.BeginOnUIThread, which still did not work. It just jumpted to 0 immediately after the loop had finished.

Comment: What do you have inside ViewCell? What is layout and children?

Comment: @YuriS A StackLayout. I've set its HeightRequest to 0 before this loop

Comment: Do you set Rowheight in your listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to solve few problems here.

1. You have to specify HasUnevenRows in list view
2. You cannot do "double i = Height" because Height will be "-1"
3. You last function setting Height using StopWatch is not really async, so you UI will not be updated till function exits.
4. Because Task.Delay is slow we can use Device timer with tick interval

Below is the solution that I tested on Android. The code is inside ViewCell in PCL

```
int currentHeight;
        public void Colapse()
        {
            currentHeight = (int)this.View.Height;
            Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(100), timerTick);
        }

        private bool timerTick()
        {
            if (currentHeight <= 0)
                return false;
            else
            {
                Height = currentHeight--;
                ForceUpdateSize();
                return true;
            }
        }
```